# addition of single precision negative floats in c

Tags: c, floating-point

I've been trying to implement floating point addition.

I believe I understand the principle:

> 1. acquire the sign, exponent, and mantissa from each float
> 2. compare which float has a higher exponent
> 3. right shift the mantissa of the lower exponent float the difference of the exponents
> 4. add that mantissa to the mantissa of the higher exponent number. If a carry were to happen (bit 23 would be occupied by the mantissa),
>      increase the exponent of the result by 1.

If a number isn't 0, also take into consideration the hidden 1 that would precede the mantissa when shifting

This does work for strictly positive numbers. But what about negatives?

Does adding 1 and -1 `( 1 + -1)` require to do a subtraction? what about `(-1 + -1)` or `(10 + -1)`?

How do I take the sign into consideration when working out the algorithm?

Comment: As this is tagged C:  `float a=1.0f, b=-1.0f; float c = a - b;`  But I assume you want to do the bit twiddling yourself?  :)

Comment: yes I'm interested in implementing the bit "twiddling" :)

Comment: It sounds self-evident that `a + -b` is equivalent to `a - b`. You have worked out or found most of the details already, the negative case should not be too much harder!